# android Support library

Tags: android, compatibility, android-support-library

When I want to create new android Project, everything is OK but after the last step (about activity) eclipse said it has problem and said:

> this template depends on the android Support library, which is either not install, or the template depends on a more recent version than the one you have installed.
>   [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)
>   required version 8
>   installed version: not installed

and If I use "upgrade/install" bottom, eclipse said :Android Compatibility JAR not found.

I found this solution on the net but I could not use it:
Steps:

1. Run your Android SDK Manager
2. Find Extras > support Library and delete that particular Library
3. Now Relaunch Android SDK MAnager
4. Download the Extras > support Library present

there is sth important: I am in Iran, because of the boycott, we couldn't download easily.

I use these tools:

```
Java.SE.Development.Kit.v7.0.Update.5.x86_p30download.com.exe     
Eclipse:
   Version: Juno Release
   Build id: 20120614-1722

ADT-20.0.0
platform-tools_r13-windows.zip
android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip
tools_r20-windows.zip
```

Comment: downloading this file "support_r10.zip" solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct about the way to solve the problem - you need to download a package with SDK Manager.
I'd tried to upload my libraries, but not registered at any file-upload services. So I will recommend you to use some ananymizers or smth like Tor ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor ) and download all necessary libraries for development.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try update your ADT plugins (currently `20.0.3`), go to `Eclipse > Help > Check for Updates`, not sure if this is the place in `Linux`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, but now solved by Right click on `SDKManager.exe` then `run as administrator` and download your required packages

according to : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/220558

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem so i used proxy.
in Eclipse go to  :

```
windows-->preferences-->general-->network connections
```

And for SDK manager

In the Android SDK Manager go to :

```
Tools-->options-->enter your proxy
```

Now you can update your eclipse and sdk with no problem
I hope this work for you:)